# How to handle Javascript error in Jasmine framework?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, syntax-error, jasmine

How to handle Javascript error(s) in Jasmine framework like syntax error, etc?

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object
```

(evaluating `$('{DIV_ID}').css('paddingTop').replace`)

Is it possible to catch any of Javascript (Backbone.js) critical errors in Jasmine.js?

Comment: No, you should be preventing the errors from happening. Sounds like you haven't stubbed something properly but can't help without code.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that there is no element with id `DIV_ID` so div.css('paddingTop') is going to return `undefined`.  You could do this:

```
var paddingTop = div.css('paddingTop') || '';
paddingTop.replace('a', '');
```